# How to make a regex not match if the string has a space at the end

Tags: regex, string, expression, space

I'm trying to create a regular expression that matches a string ONLY if a string does not have a space at the end.

For example these should match: "Jake" "John" "Mary Anne"

These shouldn't match: "Don " "David  "

Is this possible? I'm able to write a simple expression that disallows spaces altogether but that is an issue for some inputs.

Comment: What is the expression that gives you trouble? Where are you using it? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Try the regex below:

```
^.*\S$
```

It allows everything that does not ends with a space character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hwnZLQ/1) with explation

Comment: Why are you sure OP does not use the same regex?